# Python, GD and SGD implementation on Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient, gradient-descent

I try to understand and implement these algorithms in a simple example of linear regression. It is clear to me that the full batch gradient descent uses all the data to calculate the gradient and that the stochastic gradient descent uses only one.

Full Batch Gradient Descent:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.sample(frac=1)
X = df['X'].values
y = df['y'].values

m_current=0
b_current=0

epochs=100000
learning_rate=0.0001
N = float(len(y))

for i in range(epochs):
    y_current = (m_current * X) + b_current
    cost = sum([data**2 for data in (y-y_current)]) / N
    rmse = sqrt(cost)

    m_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(X * (y - y_current))
    b_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(y - y_current)

    m_current = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
    b_current = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)

print("RMSE: ", rmse)
```

Full Batch Gradient Descent output `RMSE:  10.597894381512043`

Now I tried to implement Stochastic Gradient Descent on this code, and it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from math import sqrt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df = df.sample(frac=1)
X = df['X'].values
y = df['y'].values

m_current=0
b_current=0

epochs=100000
learning_rate=0.0001
N = float(len(y))

mini = df.sample(n=1) # get one random row from dataset

X_mini = mini['X'].values
y_mini = mini['y'].values

for i in range(epochs):
    y_current = (m_current * X) + b_current
    cost = sum([data**2 for data in (y-y_current)]) / N
    rmse = sqrt(cost)

    m_gradient = -(2/N) * (X_mini * (y_mini - y_current))
    b_gradient = -(2/N) * (y_mini - y_current)

    m_current = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
    b_current = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)

print("RMSE: ", rmse)
```

Outputs: `RMSE:  27.941268469783633`, `RMSE:  20.919246260939282`, `RMSE:  31.100985268167648`, `RMSE:  21.023479528518386`, `RMSE:  19.920972478204785`...

The results I got using sklearn SGDRegressor (with the same settings):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt

    data= pd.read_csv('data.csv')

    x = data.X.values.reshape(-1,1)
    y = data.y.values.reshape(-1,1).ravel()

    Model = linear_model.SGDRegressor(alpha = 0.0001, shuffle=True, max_iter = 100000)
    Model.fit(x,y)
    y_predicted = Model.predict(x)

    mse = mean_squared_error(y, y_predicted)
    print("RMSE: ", sqrt(mse))
```

Otuputs: `RMSE:  10.995881334048224`, `RMSE:  11.75907544873036`, `RMSE:  12.981134247509486`, `RMSE:  12.298263437187988`, `RMSE:  12.549948073154608`...

The results obtained by the above algorithm are worse than scikit model results.. I wonder where I made a mistake? Also my algorithm is quite slower (few seconds)..

Comment: for gradient descent algorithms it is always helpful to visualize the progression of `m_current` and `b_current` in 2D space, on top of a contour plot of the error.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I will have that in mind

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you set `alpha` in `SGDClassifier` to learning rate. `alpha` is not the learning rate.

To set constant learning rate set `SGDClassifier's` `learing_rate` to `constant` and `eta0` to your learning rate.

You'd also need to set `alpha` to 0 since that's the regularization term and your implementation doesn't use that.

Also note that since these algorithms are stochastic in nature, setting `random_state` to some fixed value might be a good idea.

Comment: Model = linear_model.SGDRegressor(learning_rate = 'constant', alpha = 0, eta0 = 0.0001, shuffle=True, max_iter = 100000)

My mistake!!

Now I set it right, but again I get a lot better results:

    RMSE:  10.753194242863968,
    RMSE:  11.347666806771018,
    RMSE:  13.527890454048752,
    RMSE:  12.67379069336345,
    RMSE:  11.070171781078658...

Comment: BTW are you sure that you run the code you posted? I don't see getting new samples, you only get one sample outside the the loop

Comment: I'm pretty sure

Comment: So did you try changing that? This code looks like it shouldn't actually learn much :)

Comment: You're probably right, I'm still trying to figure it out